# Counting Basic Operations in Quicksort algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, code-analysis

I wrote a quicksort program that works.  I need to include a counter that counts the number of iterations.  In class we talked about the algorithm and concluded that element comparisons are the basic operation.  However, I don't know quite where to put the counter.  I can't seem to get the right output.  I've included my code, thanks!

```
void partition( vector<int> & S, int low, int high, int & pivotpoint )
{
vector<int> U;
int pivotitem = S.at(low);
int j = low;
int i;
for( i = low + 1; i <= high; i++)
    if( S.at(i) < pivotitem)
    {
        j++;
        swap( S[i], S[j] );
    }
pivotpoint = j;
swap( S[low], S[pivotpoint] );
}

void quicksort( vector<int> & S, int low, int high, int &basic_ops )
{
int pivotpoint = low;
if( high > low) 
{   
    partition( S, low, high, pivotpoint );
    quicksort( S, low, pivotpoint -1, basic_ops );
    quicksort( S, pivotpoint + 1, high, basic_ops );
}   
}
```

Comment: I think this purpose may justify a global variable (declared at file scope, outside the functions) even though they are usually frowned upon. (Alternatives include passing a counter around - messy in my opinion - or packaging your function in a `quicksorter` class with a member variable `int counter;` .)

Comment: I like your packaging idea.  Makes it much less messy.  However, I don't know where to the counter.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean where to define the counter, or where to actually increment it? For the latter - as you said, you want to count comparisons, so just increment it whenever your program is about to do a comparison!

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, `basic_ops` is your counter? In which case declare `int counter = 0;` just before you call `quicksort(v, 0, v.size() - 1, counter);`. If you `++basic_ops;` at the end of `quicksort()`, then `counter` will be up-to-date after your top level call and you'll be able to report it. This does not need to be global, just in the scope of the call to `quicksort()`.

Comment: Pass `basic_ops` on to `partition` - that's where your comparisons are.

Answer (score 0):

1. call quicksort as quicksort(array, 0, length -1, pointer to counter)

   ```
   void quicksort( vector<int> & S, int low, int high, int &basic_ops )

   {

   int pivotpoint = low;
   if( high > low) 
   {

       *basic_ops += high - low;

       partition( S, low, high, pivotpoint );

       quicksort( S, low, pivotpoint -1, basic_ops );

       quicksort( S, pivotpoint + 1, high, basic_ops );

   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Put the counter where the pivot is being changed